# JavaScript error in LayerSlider

Tags: javascript

When trying to animate elements using LyerSlider I get this error in line 4796, col 43:

```
TypeError: window[(ee.charAt(...).toUpperCase(...) + ee.slice(...))] is undefined
t = window[ee.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ee.slice(1)].easeIn;
```

If I remove the elements and only keeps the bacgground-image, there are no errors.

Comment: I think we may need more info

Comment: I use it in TYPO3 together with the extension sg_layerslider. What else do you nedde to know? The browser is FireFox.